# Integrating the derivative of a Dirac delta function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, dirac-delta-distributions, dipole-moment

I need to prove that $\rho=p_0{d\over dx}\delta(r-r_0)$ is the charge density of a single electric dipole in the point $r_0$ which direction is the $x$ axis. for that i should find the charge , dipole and quadrupole 
$q=\int \rho(r)dV$,
$p_i=\int r_i\rho(r)dV$,
$Q_{ia}=\int r_ir_a\rho(r)dV$.
I have no clue how to integrate a dervative of a delta function.
I do know to integrate $\int f(x){d\over dx}\delta(x)dx$ but I'm not sure thats the case in here.

Comment: Did you try to integrate by parts, $\int f(x){d\over dx}\delta(x)dx=-\int f'(x)\delta(x)dx=-f'(0)$?

Comment: Hey Christopher thanks for your answer in my case f'(x)=0 , correct me if im wrong

Comment: @YarinShani Are you sure that $\rho = p_0 \frac{d}{dx}(\delta(x-x_0))$ is not missing an overall negative sign?

Comment: Just copied the exact question

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments you need to use integration by parts. However you need to be careful because the delta depends on $r$ while your derivative is with respect to $x$. This means you either need to transform the derivative or write the delta function as a function of $x$. In case you are unfamiliar with the delta distribution, you will need [this property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function) for the second approach.

Comment: Thank you very much